# Application-wide CORS restrictions not working

Tags: rust, cors, actix-web

I am currently running my actix-web server here: `.bind(("127.0.0.1", 8080))?` AKA: `http://localhost:8080`.

My server hosts a bunch of api endpoints. From reading the [docs](https://docs.rs/actix-cors/latest/actix_cors/struct.Cors.html) I deduced I needed to add this middleware to my `main.rs` function (launcher for actix-web) to restrict access only to xyz domain (google currently added for brevity):

```
.wrap(
     Cors::default()
     .allowed_origin("https://google.com")
     .block_on_origin_mismatch(true),
)
```

To my understanding, every request not from `https://google.com` should now be blocked, and because of the `block_on_origin_mismatch(true)`, it should return an error. However, I can still receive resources when I request from `localhost`.

Why is this the case? How do I allow requests only from xyz domain?

Thanks!

Comment: maybe you use server as requestor not the browser itself.

Comment: I've tried from Postman and Thunderclient (for testing the api) and both of them work @Ronnel

Comment: (won't let me edit my last comment) -> I mean "both work" as in they still let me access the resources even though they shouldn't.

Comment: CORS (Cross-Origin Resource Sharing) is a security feature implemented by web browsers that blocks requests made to a different domain than the one that served the request. However, some tools, such as Postman, allow users to bypass these restrictions by sending requests with specific headers that indicate the request is safe to perform.